# Kendo UI not loading data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

I am using Kendo UI (Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC R3 2018) and I attempt to load data into it but the grid appears only showing header columns without the data. I have also tried debugging but I can't figure what the problem is. I also tried [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112387/mvc-kendo-grid-not-showing-any-data)  but it doesn't solve my problem.
Below is what I have done and I am expecting the grid to show the data.

Model

```
public partial class PlacementType
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Placement Name")]
    public string PlacementName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created By")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string Description{get; set;}
 }
```

View

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PlacementType>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.PlacementName);
            columns.Bound(c => c.DateCreated);
            columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedBy);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
        }
    )
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Refresh(true).PageSizes(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "PlacementType"))
        .PageSize(20)
    )
)
```

Controller Action

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     List<PlacementType> types = db.PlacementTypes.ToList();
     return View(types);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should have a method which returns a `Json` result.

E.g.

```
public JsonResult GetPlacementTypes()
{
     var types = db.PlacementTypes.ToList();
     return Json(types, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And update your view to use this method. (Assume your controller is called "PlacementTypeController")

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetPlacementTypes", "PlacementType"))
```

Comment: @AmanG Plz accept the answer and upvote the post if it's helpful.

Comment: @Salmon i have upvoted but my vote can't change publicly displayed post score

Comment: @AmanG He means accept the answer. Green checkbox next to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You define the following Read Action:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("Index", "PlacementType"))
```

Therefore make sure your Controller is named `PlacementTypeController` (with standard convention). The method needs to be named `Index`. That`s how you have configured it above.

<sub>If Index is already used by your view, you need to change `read.Action` *Index* to *SomethingElse*. Make sure, you Controller Action is also called *SomethingElse* Then.</sub>

Then the following Code should work:

```
public ActionResult Index([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    // var breakPoint = db.PlacementTypes.ToList(); // uncomment and set a breakpoint to see if you have data
    return Json(db.PlacementTypes.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Note the use of the `DataSourceRequest` Attribute and the `ToDataSourceResult` method.

If it`s still not working, uncomment the comment, and set a breakpoint. Is your database actualy returning data?

Also take a look in the Browser Console <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> and show if there are any errors. Also take a look at the Network tab.